# PHP - Foreach loop only echoing first letter of string

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array that looks like this:

```
array(1) { 
    ["brookybear"]=> array(5) { 
        ["id"]=> int(20217894) 
        ["name"]=> string(10) "Brookybear" 
        ["profileIconId"]=> int(603) 
        ["summonerLevel"]=> int(30) 
        ["revisionDate"]=> float(1397388011000) 
    } 
}
```

when i var_dump(); it.  I'm trying to use a foreach loop to take the "name" value out of it.  However, when I echo it, I only get "B" as the output, and not the full Brookybear.

Here is my foreach loop:

```
$url="APIURL";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
$array = json_decode($result, true);
foreach($array['brookybear'] as $champs)
{
echo $champs['name'];
}
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($champs)` shows inside the loop?

Comment: You have a bunch of extra `curl` and `json` stuff going on - are you sure the array you show is the one you get from `json_decode($result, true)`? If so, you should trim your question down a bit.

Comment: @Ben int(20217894) string(10) "Brookybear" int(603) int(30) float(1397388011000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're looping on the 'brookybear' item instead of the parent array.

If you want to see all the `name`s of all the `$champ`s:

```
$array = json_decode($result, true);
foreach($array as $champs)
{
    echo $champs['name'];
}
```

or more clearly:

```
$champions = json_decode($result, true);
foreach($champions as $champ)
{
    echo $champ['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use loop to get the value? If I am doing this, I will simply write：

```
<?php
if ( isset( $array['brookybear']['name'] ) ) {
    echo $array['brookybear']['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If first character is only display in string, you know what is the reason i now,

### make sure array variable name is not same in your above script

. example

```
$my_var = "My name is umair";
```

and below you same use this variable for array

```
$my_var[0] = "My name is umair";
```

now if you echo array var it will show only first letter in output is "M"
simply change the array variable than it will be working